# Icons to bottom of li div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get something like this:

[image: Li]

It's a bunch of list items on top of each other.
Problem now is,

1) If I do position fixed and give them bottom 0 and a margin that they get pushed out once I resize the window.

2) Same thing for position absolute / bottom 0.

3) If I give margin-top it varies on the length of the vacancy, hence it disappears if the text is too long or is way too close to the text if it it short.

So my question is, how can I make sure that whatever size the box is and whatever size the div above it is it will always stay in the position like displayed below here.

My structure so  far:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 funky">
    <div id="tinderslide">
      <ul>
        <% @vacancies.each do |vacancy| %>
          <li id="<%= vacancy.id %>">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <i class="fa fa-map-marker markervaca location"> <%= vacancy.city %></i>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <%= image_tag("mcdo.png", class: "company-logo") %>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <p class="loonvaca">€<%= vacancy.wage%>/u</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3"></div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="vactitle"><%= vacancy.name %></p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <p class="vacbeschrijving"><%= vacancy.description %></p>
            </div>
            <div class="row" >
              <div class="datumeen">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar bottom-left"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-car bottom-left-second"></i>
                <text class="jobtype">TEMP</text>
              </div>
            </div>
            <% @jobtype = Jobtype.find(vacancy.jobtype_id).name %>
            <%= link_to "", create_friendship_path(vacancy_id: vacancy.id),method: :post, :id => "Vacancy_#{vacancy.id}", :remote => true%>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="row accept-or-deny">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
          <%= link_to image_tag("kruis.png", class: "kruis"), root_path %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
          <%= link_to image_tag("share.png", class: "share"), root_path %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
          <%= link_to image_tag("vink.png", class: "vink"), root_path %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With css;

```
#tinderslide {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

#tinderslide > ul > li {
  height: 400px;
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: 12.5%;
}


#tinderslide {
  background: none;
  height: 400px;
}


#tinderslide > ul > li > div {
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
}

#tinderslide > ul > li {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white;
}

.company-logo{
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-left: 35%;
  margin-top: 15%;
  background-color: white;
}

.markervaca {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.loonvaca {
  font-size: 13px;
  top: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  margin-top: 12%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#tinderslide > ul > li {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.bottom-left {
  color: #807E7F;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 0%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.bottom-left-second {
  color: #807E7F;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.jobtype {
  bottom: 3%;
  right: 5%;
  font-family: Impact;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #807E7F;
  float: right;

}

.location {
  top: 0%;
  left: 5%;
  margin-top: 15%;
}


.vacbeschrijving {
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.vactitle {
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.accept-or-deny {
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 13.9%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    height: 65px;
    width: 67.5%;
    border-radius: 4px;
}


.kruis {
  height: 55px;
  margin-top: 4%;
  margin-left: 18%;
}

.vink {
  height: 55px;
  margin-top: 4%;
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.share {
  height: 55px;
  margin-top: 4%;
  margin-left: 33%;
}
```

Comment: Please post the HTML/CSS you have so far. (Simplified if possible)

Comment: Content is getting pushed out vertically or horizontally?

Comment: Both ways. Vertically if description text is too long, horizontally if the size changes of the div when resizing the window and bootstrap grid does its work.

Answer (score 3):

Although you have not posted generated HTML .. Still try to give :

```
li { position: relative;}
.icon { position: absolute; left: 10px; bottom: 10px; }
```

for more understating **[read this concept](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_absolute)** 
some more : [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: Better to not provide link to w3schools, try providing links to some standard documentations such as 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: I added that link because that was very easy to understand. I added your link too :). Thanks